# Get the difference of two arrays of objects by comparing values from a particular column/property

Tags: php, arrays, object, filtering, array-difference

I know there is `array_diff` and `array_udiff` for comparing the difference between two arrays, but how would I do it with two arrays of objects?

```
array(4) {
    [0]=>
        object(stdClass)#32 (9) {
            ["id"]=>
            string(3) "205"
            ["day_id"]=>
            string(2) "12"
        }
}
```

My arrays are like this one, I am interested to see the difference of two arrays based on `id` column values.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

This is exactly what [`array_udiff`](http://us.php.net/array_udiff) is for. Write a function that compares two objects the way you would like, then tell `array_udiff` to use that function. Something like this:

```
function compare_objects($obj_a, $obj_b) {
  return $obj_a->id - $obj_b->id;
}

$diff = array_udiff($first_array, $second_array, 'compare_objects');
```

Or, if you're using PHP >= 5.3 you can just use an [anonymous function](http://us.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) instead of declaring a function:

```
$diff = array_udiff($first_array, $second_array,
  function ($obj_a, $obj_b) {
    return $obj_a->id - $obj_b->id;
  }
);
```

Comment: Your comparison function won't work, a quick fix would be to change the `==` to `-`.

Comment: Right you are, salathe. Fixed.

Comment: Thank you, it was the `-` that was throwing me off.

Comment: Note: in *compare_objects*, you can return 0, to tell that the objects are equal. and -1  to tell that they are different .

Comment: The internals of this function seem to use some sorting, so you really have to return -1 or 1 when the objects are not equal, so @FranciscoCorralesMorales's comment is not correct.

Comment: Note: you could use spaceship operator from PHP 7.4 (<=>) instead of -

Answer (score 7):

Here's another option, if you want to run the diff according to object *instances*. You would use this as your callback to `array_udiff`:

```
function compare_objects($a, $b) {
    return strcmp(spl_object_hash($a), spl_object_hash($b));
}
```

You'd only want to use that if you're certain that the arrays both contain only objects - [here's my personal use case](https://github.com/penoonan/collection-of).

Comment: and what about `return $a === $b ? 0 : -1` ? Wouldn't it do the same by comparing object variables pointing to the same object instance?

Comment: The internals of this function seem to use some sorting, so you really have to return -1 or 1 when the objects are not equal, so @Dimitry K's comment is not correct.

Answer (score 7):

And here is another option if you wanna compare string properties (e.g. name):

```
$diff = array_udiff($first_array, $second_array,
  function ($obj_a, $obj_b) {
    return strcmp($obj_a->name, $obj_b->name);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on this

```
/**
     * Compare two objects (active record models) and return the difference. It wil skip ID from both objects as 
     * it will be obviously different
     * Note: make sure that the attributes of the first object are present in the second object, otherwise
     * this routine will give exception.
     * 
     * @param object $object1
     * @param object $object2
     * 
     * @return array difference array in key-value pair, empty array if there is no difference
     */
    public static function compareTwoObjects($object1, $object2)
    {
        $differences=[];
        foreach($object1->attributes as $key => $value) {
            if($key =='id'){
                continue;
            }
            if($object1->$key != $object2->$key){
                $differences[$key] = array(
                                            'old' => $object1->$key,
                                            'new' => $object2->$key
                                        );
            }
        }
        return $differences;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two arrays containing objects -- using `array_udiff()` is certainly appropriate for this task.

I'll demonstrate this technique with modern syntax ("spaceship operator" and "arrow function syntax").

Consider this sample dataset:

```
$array1 = [
    (object) ['id' => '204', 'day_id' => '12'],
    (object) ['id' => '205', 'day_id' => '13'],
    (object) ['id' => '206', 'day_id' => '14'],
    (object) ['id' => '207', 'day_id' => '15'],
];
$array2 = [
    (object) ['id' => '203', 'day_id' => '11'],
    (object) ['id' => '205', 'day_id' => '13'],
    (object) ['id' => '207', 'day_id' => '14'],
    (object) ['id' => '209', 'day_id' => '17'],
];
```

The returned data from `array_udiff()` will be the rows from the first array that are not matched in the second array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/k65rY))

```
var_export(
    array_udiff(
        $array1,
        $array2,
        fn($a, $b) => $a->id <=> $b->id
    )
);
```

returns these two rows:

```
[
    (object) ['id' => '204', 'day_id' => '12'],
    (object) ['id' => '206', 'day_id' => '14'],
]
```

---

Reversing the order of the first two parameters: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Wf6tS))

```
[
    (object) ['id' => '203', 'day_id' => '11'],
    (object) ['id' => '209', 'day_id' => '17'],
)
```