# PHP remove array items from another if exists

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-difference

I have 2 object arrays: Array A and Array B. how can I check if object from Array B exists in Array A. and if exists remove it from Array A.

Example:

```
Array A:
   [
       {"id": 1, "name": "item1"},
       {"id": 2, "name": "item2"},
       {"id": 3, "name": "item3"},
       {"id": 4, "name": "item4"}
   ]

Array B 
   [
       {"id": 1, "name": "item1"},
       {"id": 3, "name": "item3"}
   ]
```

After removing Array A should look like:

```
   [
       {"id": 2, "name": "item2"},
       {"id": 4, "name": "item4"}
   ]
```

Comment: You can use such trick which I see anywhere - `$ArrayA = array_map('serialize', $ArrayA);
$ArrayB = array_map('serialize', $ArrayB);
$ArrayA = array_diff($ArrayA, $ArrayB);
$ArrayA = array_map('unserialize', $ArrayA);
print_r($ArrayA);`

Comment: I found answer in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6472183/php-get-difference-of-two-arrays-of-objects)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_udiff](http://php.net/array_udiff), and you can refer to these post for array compare [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821680/array-diff-with-multidimensional-arrays) and [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678959/php-check-if-two-arrays-are-equal).   [**live demo**](https://eval.in/788693)

```
print_r(array_udiff($A, $B, function($a, $b){return $a['id'] == $b['id'] && $a['name'] == $b['name'] ? 0 : -1;}));
```

Comment: what am I doing wrong? - https://eval.in/788682

Comment: @splash58 It's my fault, I edit it now. and added the demo, you can check it now.  Thank you for you comment.

Comment: what i still do wrong ? - https://eval.in/788701

Comment: @splash58, in the question it's array, not ojbect.

Comment: array of objects

Answer (score 0):

Here we are using `array_map` which first convert `object`'s to string using `json_encode` which will convert array to `json string` then we are finding `array_diff` for both the array's.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/788707)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$array1=
[
    (object) ["id"=> 1, "name"=> "item1"],
    (object) ["id"=> 2, "name"=> "item2"],
    (object) ["id"=> 3, "name"=> "item3"],
    (object) ["id"=> 4, "name"=> "item4"]
];
$array1=array_map(function($value){return json_encode($value);}, $array1);
$array2=
[
    (object) ["id"=> 1, "name"=> "item1"],
    (object) ["id"=> 3, "name"=> "item3"]
];
$array2=array_map(function($value){return json_encode($value);}, $array2);

$result=array_map(function($value){return json_decode($value);}, array_diff($array1, $array2));
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

`array_filter` might help.

```
$a =  [
       ["id"=> 1, "name"=> "item1"],
       ["id"=> 2, "name"=> "item2"],
       ["id"=> 3, "name"=> "item3"],
       ["id"=> 4, "name"=> "item4"]
   ];


print_r(array_filter($a, function($e) { 
  return  !in_array($e, [["id"=> 1, "name"=> "item1"],["id"=> 3, "name"=> "item3"]]);
}));
/* =>
    Array

(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => item2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => item4
        )

)  
 */
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.in-array.php