# Uncaught PHP exception

Tags: php, exception, php-7.2

I have the following code:

```
set_error_handler(
    function ($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline, array $errcontex) {
        throw new Exception($errstr, 0);
    },
    E_ALL
);

class Foo
{
    public function asd(): int
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

class Bar
{
    public function asd(): int
    {
        return 1;
    }
}


$a = [
    1 => new Foo(),
    2 => new Bar(),
];

try {
    array_diff([], $a);
} catch (Throwable $exception)
{
    var_dump("11");
}
```

When I run it, it results in the following error: `PHP Warning:  Uncaught Exception: Object of class Foo could not be converted to string in /oms/bebe.php:5 Stack trace: ...`. That is, an exception doesn't seem to be caught despite `set_error_handler` is in place. What's even more weird, when I declare an `$a` array with a single element,

```
$a = [
    2 => new Bar(),
];
```

everything works fine, that is, an exception is caught and `11` is output.

How come? And how can I catch that exception with an arbitrary array element amount?

Comment: Not really helpful, but might be something with 7.2, seems to work in 7.3 and 7.4

Comment: The same thing in php 7.3 actually

Comment: Looks like you'll need to use `array_udiff` with a supplied callback function as `array_diff` can only compare arrays. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6472227/9238321

Comment: There are plenty of options actually, and the question is not how to compare two arrays after all. The question is why I can't catch an exception.